# Jenkins agent failure not detected by systemd

Tags: jenkins, websocket, systemd

I run the Jenkins agent.jar as a systemd [service](https://gist.github.com/cidermole/eccc5896658e4a99e674e20e80aafcb2) on a VM in our environment. The Jenkins agents connect to the Jenkins controller using Websockets.

However, occasionally, the Jenkins agent on the VM fails with the following exception, which disconnects the agent from the controller.

```
 java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.write(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:367)
         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.write(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:400)
         at java.base/java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel.write(AsynchronousSocketChannel.java:582)
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.TransportFilter.write(TransportFil>
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.SslFilter$WriteQueue$1.run(SslFilt>
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.SslFilter$WriteQueue.write(SslFilt>
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.SslFilter.handleWrite(SslFilter.ja>
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.SslFilter.write(SslFilter.java:162)
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.TaskQueueFilter$WriteTask.execute(>
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.TaskQueueFilter.processTask(TaskQu>
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.TaskQueueFilter.write(TaskQueueFil>
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.ClientFilter$JdkWriter.write(Clien>
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.spi.Writer.write(Writer.java:62)
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ProtocolHandler.write(ProtocolHandler.java:496)
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ProtocolHandler.send(ProtocolHandler.java:251)
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ProtocolHandler.send(ProtocolHandler.java:246)
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ProtocolHandler.stream(ProtocolHandler.java:420)
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocket.sendBinary(TyrusWebSocket.java:481)
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocket.sendBinary(TyrusWebSocket.java:451)
         at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusRemoteEndpoint$Basic.sendBinary(TyrusRemoteEn>
         at hudson.remoting.Engine$1AgentEndpoint$Transport.write(Engine.java:645)
         at hudson.remoting.AbstractByteBufferCommandTransport.write(AbstractByteBufferCommandTransport.java:303)
         at hudson.remoting.Channel.send(Channel.java:765)
         at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$PhantomReferenceImpl.cleanup(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:397)
         at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$Unexporter.run(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:614)
         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
         at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:121)
         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
 Oct 05, 2023 5:04:28 PM hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$Unexporter run 
~
```

systemd does not detect this exception as a failure and hence does not restart the process. How can systemd detect this failure and restart the Java process ?

Comment: What's the return code of the failed process? If it's 0, systemd will assume it exited cleanly.

Comment: I am unsure how I get the failed process's return code. Also, the problem is extremely difficult to reproduce but occurs every few days. Another related thread with a similar issue can be found at https://community.jenkins.io/t/jenkins-agents-randomly-disconnecting-from-controller/2112/7

Comment: I'm not sure what your deployment setup is, but you could use a simple wrapper script to do the launching, and record nonzero error codes to a log file. Then, instead of your systemd service launching the agent, it launches the wrapper script. If the logfile is empty after a crash, you know it's crashing with a return code of 0.